# Does a capistrano deploy.rb file contain server credentials?

Tags: php, capistrano

This is my first time using Capistrano and I am getting server authentication errors right at the start of my deploy:setup stage. I am a PHP user using rvm on a mac.

I noticed my deploy.rb file does not contain the password to my server. It only contains the password to my private git repo. Is there an attribute available for setting the server password so my connection could authenticate?

Do deploy.rb files list server credentials?

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to refer you to a [related discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241639/multiple-server-deploy-asking-ssh-password-for-each-server/8248860#8248860). Point in case: It's better to setup publickey authentication for your servers, it saves you from having your credentials stored in plain text and it is safer to begin with.

If you use github for your git hosting, you can use your publickey there as well. Be sure to use `ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true` to forward your publickey to the server when deploying.

If you really want to set your user and password, I believe you can do it as follows:

```
set :user, "sshuser"
set :password, "sshpassword"
set :scm_passphrase, "gitpassword"
```

More info can be found at [github help/capistrano](http://help.github.com/deploy-with-capistrano/)

Comment: I did all this @HectorMalot. But here is the error I get:

    connection failed for: [ip_address_omitted]      (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: root), app_name_ommitted       (Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Operation timed out - connect(2)

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer covers good info about deploy and i agree it is better to setup public keys.

But if you have password issues, try to add this line:

```
default_run_options[:pty] = true
```

to your deploy.rb file, so you allow Capistrano to prompt for passwords.

Answer (score 0):

@Amit Erandole (in reply to [ip_address_omitted] (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: root), app_name_ommitted (Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Operation timed out - connect(2)):
Looks like root access over ssh is not allowed on the server (and generally not recommended). Try it again with a valid user or turn root access on in sshd_config (PermitRootLogin yes).
But as was already mentioned by HectorMalot, create an ssh-key and forget about the passwords. ;)

Comment: I have created sshkeys and placed them on the server. But I still get this error. sshd_config is a file on my server, correct?

Comment: That is correct. Check that _PubkeyAuthentication_ is set to _yes_ (default on most systems).
Besides that, you need to copy _only_ the public key to the server and save it in _.ssh/_ folder of user with whom you're going to log in. You need to be aware that the file naming convention is _authorized\_keys_ .

Comment: If forgot to add that _authorized\_keys_ must have the restrictive file permissions, e.g. _644_

Now all that is left is the configuration in your client in _.ssh/config_ (or pass your private key via the _-i_ flag to ssh):
Host <ServerName>
  IdentityFile "~/.ssh/<id_rsa>"

Comment: Sorry, the last step isn't clear - you're saying id_rsa on my computer is a private key and it needs go on the server inside the a config file within the ssh folder? But there is no config file on my server. should I make one and then copy my private key a.k.a id_rsa?

Comment: @AmitErandole No. The config file should to be created on the client, else you would have to pass the path to the identityfile as a parameter to ssh everytime. What you need to copy is `id_rsa.pub` aka the public key to the server and save it as `authorized_keys` in the `.ssh` folder of the user you're connecting as. `id_rsa` is the default name, so if you changed it during creation use yours obv. Just google for a how-to, eg http://www.debuntu.org/ssh-key-based-authentication