# Capistrano, sudo command and multiple passwords

Tags: ssh, capistrano, sudo

I use capistrano to run a command. I have ssh-key based authentication but a different sudo password on each machine.

My capfile looks like this

```
default_run_options[:pty] = true
role :admin, "server1","server2","server3"

desc "myCommand"
task :mycommand, :roles=>:admin do
    run "cd <workdir> && #{sudo} <command>"
end
```

When i run this i get the following output:

```
  * executing `myCommand'
  * executing "cd <workdir> && sudo -p 'sudo password: ' <command>"
    servers: ["server1", "server2", "server3"]
    [server2] executing command
    [server3] executing command
Password: 
 ** [out :: server2] 
 ** [out :: server3] 
    [server1] executing command
 ** [out :: server1] 
 ** [out :: server3] CMD-OUTPUT
*** [out :: server2] Sorry, try again.
 ** [out :: server2] Sorry, try again.
Password: 
 ** [out :: server2] 
 ** [out :: server1] 
 ** [out :: server2] CMD-OUTPUT
 ** [out :: server1] 
 ** [out :: server1] Sorry, try again.
 ** [out :: server1] sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
    command finished in 14411ms
failed: "sh -c 'cd <workdir> && sudo -p '\\''sudo password: '\\'' <command>'" on server1
```

Apparently capistrano assumes that i have the same passwort on every server, is that possible? How can i fix that?

Comment: See the answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241639/multiple-server-deploy-asking-ssh-password-for-each-server

Comment: I have public-key login setup already, but i need the sudo. Can i somehow "unparallel" the runs?

Answer (score 0):

For such automated installs, it's most common to have a SSH key without a passphrase being set. The mere ownership of the private key is enough to allow login (so the file itself is effectively the password).

You can further protect the system, just in case that file should get out, by limiting in the SSH configuration which IP address the key could connect from, and what commands it is allowed to run.

Comment: I use capistrano for administrative purposes, not for deploys. So i need the sudo. Like i said, i have public-key login set up already.

Answer (score 0):

Capistrano does not support multiple servers with different passwords. Rather than changing them all to the same password, which isn't recommended, you can set the certain commands you need to run via sudo to not require a password for the user in question.

To give user bob sudo access to cat without a password, you would add this to your sudoers file:

```
bob ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/cat
```

There are obviously some security concerns here but I feel they are less than giving your cap user full sudo access to all your boxes. Be sure to read 'man sudoers' through and carefully limit the commands you allow using NOPASSWD.

Comment: That's not a good option. Is there not way to do the commands in serial instead of parallel?